# Установка языковых пакетов ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu

Нужна комманда для установки русской локали через консоль ибо гуевая установка отказывается это делать.

Answer (score 1):

`apt-cache search language-pack`, ищем нужное и `apt-get`.

Comment: apt-search: команда не найдена

Comment: sudo aptitude search language-pack-ru, а потом можно sudo aptitude install <то что нашлось>

Comment: Я уже стесняюсь написать :)sudo: aptitude: команда не найдена

Comment: зачем двоеточие после sudo? попробуйте sudo apt-get language-pack-ru

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте `sudo apt-get install language-support-ru`

Comment: Пишет: Пакет language-support-ru недоступен, но упомянут в списке зависимостей другого пакета.Это может означать, что пакет отсутствует, устарел, или доступен из источников, не упомянутых в sources.list

Comment: Попробуйте еще выполнить:sudo apt-get updatesudo apt-get upgrade

Comment: gurzufnet прав, language-pack :)

Answer (score 0):

Код: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -f` и перезагрузить компьютер.

Обычно помогает.Но может не получиться.

Тогда код:

```
sudo reinstall language-selector language-selector-common && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -f
```